# manipulate imported csv data in PowerShell

Tags: csv, powershell

I have a csv file that is auto generated from an external source (NetSuite)
I am hoping to use data from the csv file to update Active Directory user accounts to add or update the "Manager"

NetSuite gives me a csv file that has Email and Manager as 2 column headers.
Email - contains the employees email address and Manager contains Manager Name in a Last, First format.

I would like to convert both of these column into data that can be used in

```
Set-AdUser -Identity user.name -manager first.last
```

Objective 1 would be to remove the @domain from the email address column
Objective 2 would be to reorder Last, First into first.last

```
Import-Csv c:\test.csv

Email | Supervisor
user.1@test.com | "Number1, Manager"
user.2@test.com | "Number2, Manager"
```

I'd like to be able to export this to a csv file that looks like this

```
Email   |  Supervisor
user.1  |  Manager.Number1
user.2  |  Manager.Number2
```

So the workflow I am imagining to automate the Employee - Manager field in AD is:
1. NetSuite Exports csv file at a scheduled time
2. PowerShell Script to import the NetSuite csv and edit the data as described.
3. Export-Csv to new csv with the usable data
4. PowerShell script to Set-AdUser -Manager from new csv

All that I am seek guidance on are Steps 2 and 3

Is this possible?  I will update if I figure this out on my own.

edit

I have figured out Objective 1
Now all I need to be able to do is to take "Last, First" data from a column and change it to "First.Last"

edit 2 - This doesn't seem to work quiet right....

```
$txt = import-csv .\book1.csv | % {
  $_.Email = $_.Email -replace "@test.com", ""
  $_
}
export-csv -InputObject $txt -NoTypeInformation .\newbook1.csv
```

Comment: Welcome to _StackOverflow_, you might want to read [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before doing so. Give a bit of context explaining what do you need, what have you tried so far, and why it isn't working as expected (i.e.: error messages, etc.). Also consider taking the time to format your question to be easily understood by readers. You may want to edit your question to include the clarifications you posted on the comments above.

Comment: Thanks Nacho.  I tried to provide some context. and moved my solution code into a snippet

Comment: Search for the `-split` and `-join` operators

Comment: What is the separator in your csv file. I assume it should be a comma. Then how is the value in your csv has comma in it for the manager column. Please paste exact source csv contents in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Import-Csv -Path .\book1.csv | ForEach-Object {
  #Remove @AndEverthingThatFollows
  $_.Email = $_.Email -replace "@.*$"
  #Replace "LastName, FirstName" (space optional) with FirstName.Lastname    
  $_.Supervisor = $_.Supervisor -replace '(\w+),\s*?(\w+)', '$2.$1'
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path .\newbook1.csv
```